# A marble is dropped straight down from point $A$

Tags: calculus

> A marble is dropped straight down from point $A$. The time required
>   for the ball to travel the distance $h_1$ between $A$ and $B$ is equal
>   to the required time to travel the distance $h_2$ between $B$ and $C$.
>   Find $\dfrac{h_1}{h_2}$ by using $g \approx 10$ $m/s^2$.

I am not sure how to start the solution. All the distance is: $h=\dfrac{gt^2}{2}$, where $g\approx$ $10$ $m/s^2$ and $h=\dfrac{10(t+t)^2}{2}=\dfrac{10(2t)^2}{2}=\dfrac{10\cdot 4t^2}{2}=\dfrac{40t^2}{2}=20t^2$. We can calculate $h_1$ : 
  $h_1=\dfrac{a_1t^2}{2}$. Here ($h_2$) we have initial speed, that according to me is equal to $a_1t$. Therefore, $h_2=\dfrac{a_1t^2+a_2t^2}{2}$ and$h_1+h_2=\dfrac{a_1t^2}{2}+\dfrac{a_1t^2+a_2t^2}{2}=\dfrac{2a_1t^2+a_2t^2}{2}=20t^2$. It seems like I can't finish the problem in this way.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$h_1= (1/2)gt^2$$

$$h_1+h_2= (1/2)g(2t)^2 = 2gt^2= 4h_1$$

$$ h_2= 3h_1$$

$$\frac {h_1}{h_2}= \frac {1}{3}$$

Comment: Why $h_1=\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova  Newtons's Law of motion.

Answer (score 2):

From first principles. The equation for velocity is

$ v = u + ft $

The equation for distance is

$s = ut + \frac{1}{2} f t^2$

---

So from $A$ to $B$

$v1 = gt $
$h1 = \frac{1}{2} g t^2$

And from $B$ to $C$

$h2 = gt^2 + \frac{1}{2} g t^2$

---

So

$ \frac {h 1}{h 2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} g t^2}{gt^2 + \frac{1}{2} g t^2}$

Cancelling out

$ \frac {h 1}{h 2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1 + \frac{1}{2}}  = \frac{1}{3}$